# Return response after all operations complete nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Learning nodejs, how do I return the full reponse in the following request? I always seem to retrieve just a snapshot of the result. Clearly I return before all work is completed, any help please?

```
  myapp.get('/someurl', (req, res) => {
      dbconn.connection.then((conn) => {
        conn.getdata().then((data) => {
          if (data != null) { 
            var foo = new foo();
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= data.foos.length - 1; i++) {

              foo.Id = data.foos[i].myid;
              foo.name = data.foos[i].atamyname;
              foo.siblings = _.filter(data.foos, (fo) => {
                  if(fo.Id === data.foos[i].myid ){
                    return fo;
                  }
              });
              result.push(foo);
            }
            return result;
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: You're just using the same `foo` object over and over in your loop, not creating a new one each time.  So, each time through the loop, you're just modifying the original `foo` object.  FYI, variables and properties named `foo`, `foos` and `fo` are not very helpful in following the code.  And, you don't show any code that attempts to actually do anything with the result which makes it confusing about "where" you don't see the full result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of things you have this in a router (perhaps `express`) and the first line indicates you're handling a `GET` request for `/someurl`.  Note that the first function takes 2 parameters: `req` and `res`. Your code does not make use of them though, so you may not understand how the data gets returned to the caller.

Functions of the form `(req, res, next)` are called `middleware` functions and the parameters have specific purposes:

- req - the incoming http request object
- res - the outgoing http response object
- next - can be used to tell the router to continue or throw an error

When your function has collected the data it needs to, you should send it back to the caller using the `res` object. For example, if you wanted to return a JSON object with some data your call might look like this:

```
 myapp.get('/someurl', (req, res) => {
   return res.json({message: "it worked"});
 }
```

In your case you want to send back the results of doing your data processing, so you could just replace your line that says `return result;` with this:

```
  return res.json(result);
```

This tells the http response to set the `resultCode` to 200 and the response `body` to the `result` array in JSON form.

There are other `res` functions that could be used if JSON isn't the format you want to return. See [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) for more details.

The problem with your original implementation is that the return value is not used by the router.

Also, you need to handle the case where `data` did come back as `null` somehow. Perhaps by using `return res.status(404).end()` or `return res.json([])`.

Beyond that you may not be building your `result` array properly. Note that you create one `foo` instance and keep pushing that one object onto the array. You should create a new `foo` object each time through the loop or you'll just keep modifying the same object repeatedly. Try this:

```
if (data != null) { 
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.foos.length - 1; i++) {
    var foo = new foo();  // <-- create a fresh one inside the loop
    foo.Id = data.foos[i].myid;
    foo.name = data.foos[i].atamyname;
    foo.siblings = _.filter(data.foos, (fo) => {
      if(fo.Id === data.foos[i].myid ){
        return fo;
      }
    });
    result.push(foo);
  }
  return res.json(result);
}
```

Comment: return res.json(result) does not return the full response

Comment: what do you consider a "full response"?

Comment: I expect to see 4 objects return, however I always returned 1 which is the last one

Comment: Actually ignore me, the issue was that I was returning always the last element in the array as a result in my code! jheez

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I think is wrong with the array building

Comment: plus1 for a detailed answer

Comment: thanks @Harry - did my comment about reusing the `foo` object instead of creating a new one each time help?

Comment: that is what I ended up doing as that was the mistake in my logic

Comment: great - glad you're past the problem. if you feel it's right, please mark my answer as accepted (or not if you don't - it's fine)

Comment: i'll mark it for the great explanation to help someone in the future, in my instance it was a logical error :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
return res.json(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is not the issue. I do get a response but not the full response.